# Indentation messing up Nested Property Drawers

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor, unity-editor

I have this Class called ToggledFloat. It wraps a float but also adds a bool telling if it is enabled or not.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ToggledFloat
{
    public float value;
    public bool enabled = false;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ClassWIthNestedProp
{
    public ToggledFloat aTogFloat;
}

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ClassWIthNestedProp eCA;
    public ToggledFloat tF;
}
```

I can easily make a Custom Property Drawer for this, and it looks right, when the editor draws this property at indentation level "0". However when I look at ToggledFloat properties nested inside another property they look wrong.

My propertyDrawer looks like this:

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ToggledFloat))]
public class ToggledPropertyEditor : PropertyDrawer
{

    public override float GetPropertyHeight (SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        var propVal = property.FindPropertyRelative("value");
        float contentUnfoldedHeight = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight (propVal, label);
        return contentUnfoldedHeight;
    }

    // Draw the property inside the given rect
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        int iL = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
        //EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0; //- Set this to "0" to make thing work but non-indented
        SerializedProperty valueProp = property.FindPropertyRelative("value");
        SerializedProperty enabledProp = property.FindPropertyRelative("enabled");

        //Label left of checkbox
        float labelWidth = GUI.skin.label.CalcSize(label).x;
        Rect labelRect = new Rect(0/*position.x*/, position.y, labelWidth, 16);
        EditorGUI.LabelField(labelRect, label, GUIContent.none);
        EditorGUI.DrawRect(labelRect, new Color(0,0,1,.1f));

        //Checkbox
        Rect enableRect = new Rect();
        enableRect.xMin = labelRect.xMax;
        enableRect.yMin = labelRect.yMin;
        enableRect.width = 16;
        enableRect.height = 16;
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(enableRect, enabledProp, GUIContent.none);
        EditorGUI.DrawRect(enableRect, new Color(0,1,0,.1f));

        //Value
        Rect valueRect = new Rect();
        valueRect.xMin = enableRect.xMax;
        valueRect.yMin = enableRect.yMin;
        valueRect.xMax = position.xMax;
        valueRect.yMax = position.yMax;

        EditorGUI.DrawRect(valueRect, new Color(1,0,0,.1f));
        bool enabled = GUI.enabled;
        GUI.enabled = enabledProp.boolValue;
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(valueRect, valueProp, new GUIContent(""), true);
        GUI.enabled = enabled;
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = iL;

    }
}
```

When the inspector draws an instance of class Test, it looks like this:
[image]

The Colored rects are only there for allowing me to debug where those rects actually are. The weird thing is that the text-labels are offset from the coloured rects, even though they get the same rect as argument. This is of course only a problem if I want coloured rects in my inspector - but the real problem is that it seems that this offset problem causes nested checkboxes to not work. I cannot click checkboxes on a nested property.

If I then explicitly set EditorGUI.IndenLevel = 0, then the coloured rects and the labels coincide and the toggle buttons work properly - but I then loose the automatic indentation, that I would really like to use.

[image]

Can someone tell me what I am overlooking

Answer (score 0):

The DrawRect method doesn't consider the indent level. You have to adjust rect yourself to draw indented rectangle. Fortunately, There is a function to get the intented rect.

[From UnityCsReference EditorGUI](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/EditorGUI.cs#L3564)

```
static void DrawIndentedRect(Rect rect, Color color)
{
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(EditorGUI.IndentedRect(rect), color);
}
```

[Captured Inspector IndentedRect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE4vG.png)

However it doesn't work properly.

From the [implementation of IndentedRect](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/EditorGUI.cs#L3564), it reduces the width of rect.

```
static void DrawIndentedRect(Rect rect, Color color)
{
    // Indent per level is 15
    rect.x += EditorGUI.indentLevel * 15;
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(rect, color);
}
```

or

```
static void DrawIndentedRect(Rect rect, Color color)
{
    var indentedRect = EditorGUI.IndentedRect(rect);
    indentedRect.width = rect.width;
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(indentedRect, color);
}
```

[Captured Inspector DrawIndentedRect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd3uD.png)